# Javac working with Powershell but not Command Prompt

Tags: java, powershell, windows-10, command-prompt

I am trying to install Java in Windows 10 Home (64 bit). Like many tutorials point out, I downloaded the Java jdk setup file, executed it and once installed changed the Path in the Environment Variables. But for some reason, when I execute the command 'javac' it returns the not internal/external command error in Command Prompt but runs absolutely fine in Powershell. I tried to rectify this by uninstalling Java and reinstalling it very carefully, following all the steps but still this keeps on happening.

Also, during installation of Java, I lost the original value to my Path variable. Could this be causing the problem?

**Edit** : I was able to get the *java* command running in the command prompt but *javac* still won't work. I've already tried the methods suggested on other forums and this one but no luck so far.

Comment: For some reason the Java compiler doesn't seem to be in the PATH with CMD. Check the output of `echo %PATH%` in CMD and `$env:Path` in PowerShell. Do both list your Java `bin` directory?

Comment: Yes, they both do. Bin for both jdk and jre is visible in the Path in both Command Prompt and Powershell.

Comment: Can you run `javac` (e.g. `javac --help`) when you `cd` into the `bin` directory first? Does it work when you run `javac.exe` instead of `javac` (without extension)?

Comment: Yes (Tested in Command Prompt). No, it doesn't work when I type javac.exe but I haven't navigated to the bin directory for executing javac.exe

Comment: That were two questions. Which does your "yes" refer to? The first, the second, or both?

Comment: Edited my answer. Javac.exe works too when I navigate to the bin directory though.

Comment: @PixieDev - Try rebooting the system, and then check the same!

Comment: I actually tried that a few times before posting the question. Didn't work.

Comment: Run [SysInternals Process Monitor (ProcMon)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) while you try and launch `javac` in command prompt, and see where in the filesystem the command prompt looks for it, and whether it finds anything?

Comment: The process monitor showed that when I tried it out, it gave a 'Name not found' and 'Name Invalid' result.

Comment: For clarity: does `javac.exe` only work when you're in the `bin` directory, or does it also work from other locations?

Comment: Only in the bin directory but this is just limited to command prompt. It works fine in the Powershell as I described earlier.

Answer (score 1):

See there is no problem with Java installation if you can find JDK(Java development kit) and JRE(Server Java runtime environment) in programme files in windows in a JAVA folder.

The main problem is with the environment variable declaration.

Go to environment variables and make a new path for that.

JAVA_HOME = "YOUR JDK & JRE INSTALLATION PATH"

And another one is

JAVA = "YOUR JDK & JRE INSTALLATION PATH"

Hope that help to you. After doing that if still there problem persisist just restart your PC and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your variable location up to /bin/

Refer to this :

https://www.windows-commandline.com/javac-not-recognized-internal-external-command/

Answer (score 0):

1. Open file explorer
2. Right click computer then click properties
3. click advanced system settings
4. click environmental variables
5. click path (for me there was one in user variables for admin and another in system variables)
6. find the directory for javac (for me it was here C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin)
7. so go back to file explorer and open program files x86
8. then open the java folder
9. then open the jdk folder
10. then open the bin folder
11. highlight the path in the search bar and copy it
12. click edit on path and paste into the path in the environmental variable for both(if you have more than one path)
13. If no path exists then create one in user variables
14. If there is any existing text place a semicolon ; between the text you pasted in there and the preexisting text.
15. close command prompt and reopen it.
16. type javac -version
17. the version info should be listed

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes up with the directory of your command prompt.
check your PowerShell and command prompt default directory.
We can run command prompt as WinKey+R then type *cmd*, Hit the enter button then check our java version cmd *javac -version*.